# Fatal Error: function getIsInStock() on a non-object in Mediafallback.php on line 112

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configurable-product, fatal-error, color-swatches

I got fatal error in configurable product after update Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.1 or 1.9.3.2.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getIsInStock() on a non-object in
magento1/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php on line 112
```

All my configurable Swatches is using by color. It is ok in Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 after click product (configurable) detail in front-end but I got problem after update Magento version. I try to check error log folder, but nothing output.

** I also try to use default theme in magento and try to Cache Storage Management but both are the same. error is still there.

please advice me how to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not optimal. You have not initialized Magento so module XML is not loaded yet and the factory pattern does not work.
Simply use either:

```
Mage::init();
```

or

```
Mage::app();
```

before using getModel.

Comment: Sorry, can you a bit explain to me? I dun understand where should i edit it? Should i edit magento original file (Mediafallback.php) or theme in product detail page?